# How can I order by more that one element with LINQ /

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ statement:

```
db.PhraseCategories.OrderBy(c => c.Name);
```

I would like to order first by GroupId and then second by Name.

Can anyone give me advice on how I can do this?

Comment: Check [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/4389/query-ordering-orderby-thenby-orderbydescending-thenbydescending#t=201608220528246349759)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`ThenBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method to performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in ascending order according to a `key`.

```
db.PhraseCategories
.OrderBy(c => c.GroupId)
.ThenBy(c => c.Name);
```

Or

```
from c in db.PhraseCategories         
orderby c.GroupId, c.Name
```

Comment: To add there are corresponding Descending options too, as default ordering is Ascending

Comment: That's correct, I listed description for `ThenBy` to explain what it do.